# Frequently dropping a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our current business requirement. We have to pull the complete data every time. We have to truncate out table and load it with 20 million rows of data.

I want to know instead of truncating. If I do a drop and load the table with `select * into`. Will this frequent dropping of table have any adverse affect on database performance in the long term? Like high fragmentation or something related to pages?

We cannot use merge as per our current data.

Just wanted to know the adverse affect of frequent drooping and creation of tables.

Comment: You might consider asking this over at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What advantage are you anticipating compared with your current process of truncating it?

Comment: Not much. Performance improvement through select * into than usual insert.

Comment: Even if it is no advantage just curious to know will dropping tabkentoo frequently can have any kind of adverse affect on my dB.

Comment: Minimal logging is available on `insert...select` since 2005. So all you will do is cause more metadata contention and have less flexibility on file group.

Comment: Dropping a table can be minimally logged. Truncate is by default minimally logged. They can both be rolled back. To save time and ressources, have you considered bulk insert?
Truncating is like a delete and will remove leafs/hash and leave pages where they are. Dropping the table will drop pages associated to the information. End result is pretty much the same.